# Warum kriegt man etwas „auf die Reihe“ und nicht „in die Reihe“?

Tags: etymology, idiom

Welchen Usprung hat die Redewendung *etwas auf die Reihe bekommen/kriegen*? Warum heißt es nicht *in die Reihe*? Und welche Reihe ist gemeint?

Answer (score 9):

### kurze Antwort:

Das »auf die Reihe bringen« war eine handwerkliche Tätigkeit, bei der man Stoff (oft den Saum eines Kleidungsstücks) mithilfe einer Nadel auf einen Faden aufzog, damit dieser Stoff später regelmäßige Falten wirft. Man zog also den Stoff **auf** eine Reihe. Das erfoderte etwas Geschick, und wenn man ungeschickt war, kriegte man den Stoff eben nicht ordentlich auf die Reihe, und das Resultat waren unregelmäßige Falten im Stoff.

---

### ausführlicher:

Heute ist eine Reihe vor allem:

- eine Gruppe Menschen, die geordnet nebeneinander oder hintereinander stehen.

  > Stellt euch schön in einer **Reihe** auf!
- eine Serie oder Folge von zusammengehörigen Dingen

  > Das Heft »Basteln mit Teebeuteln« aus der **Reihe** »Basteln mit Haushaltsmüll« war ein Flop.
- eine größere Anzahl

  > Eine **Reihe** Schaulustiger kam, um das Loch im Boden zu bestaunen.

Weitere ähnliche Verwendungen sind von diesen abgeleitet.

Aber das sind lauter Anwendungen, in denen sich etwas *in* einer Reihe befindet, oder *in* eine Reihe gegeben wird, und hilft nicht weiter, wenn man sich fragt, warum man etwas **auf** die Reihe kriegt. Man muss daher in der Vergangenheit des Wortes kramen.

Sucht man nach der Herkunft des Wortes »Reihe«, dann findet man Hinweise darauf, was früher mal eine Reihe war, nämlich:

- eine geordnete Folge
- eine Linie
- eine Grenzlinie, eine Ackergrenze
- mehrere nebeneinander stehende Häuser
- ein schmaler Gang
- eine Planke, Latte oder Messlatte
- ein Wassergraben, eine Rinne
- eine Zeile
- ein gefädelter Kleidersaum

Die zu untersuchende Redewendung geht tatsächlich auf den gefädelten Kleidersaum zurück, und diese Tatsache wird verständlicher, wenn man sich das zur Reihe gehörende Verb »**reihen**« ansieht. Dieses Wort hatte (und hat noch immer) ebenfalls eine Reihe unterschiedlicher Bedeutungen, darunter diese:

> **reihen** (Verb):
> Mit einer Nadel den Saum eines Kleidungsstücks *auf* einen Faden aufziehen, um dann diesen Saum zu raffen, also um ihn so zusammenzuziehen, dass er kleine regelmäßige Falten wirft.

Hier bringt man also etwas (nämlich den Kleiderstoff) *auf* eine Reihe, und das erforderte einiges handwerkliches Geschick. Wenn der Stoff am Ende unregelmäßige Falten wirft, hat man ihn nicht ordentlich auf die Reihe bekommen. Und das ist der Ursprung der Redewendung.

Comment: Kannst Du uns noch einen Link/Referenz zur Bedeutung im Zusammenhang mit nähen geben? Soweit ich es beurteilen kann, würde man beim Nähen die Präposition **an** benutzen (*anreihen*).

Comment: @Takkat: Es geht nicht um Nähen im herkömmlichen Sinn, sondern um das Auffädeln des Stoffs auf einem Faden: Man zieht einen kräftigen Faden durch den Stoff, wobei der Faden kürzer als der Stoff ist, so dass der Stoff gerafft wird und Falten wirft. Es entsteht also keine Naht, die irgend etwas zusammenhält. Da es um Auffädeln geht, ist meine Herleitung jener von Iris mit den Perlen sehr ähnlich. Nur gibt es beim Auffädeln von Perlen kein Geschicklichkeits-Problem; Es ist sehr leicht, Perlen auf die Reihe zu kriegen. Für den Stoff muss man die Nadel an sorgfältig gewählten Stellen einstechen.

Comment: @Takkat: Meine Quelle ist übrigens das Herkunftswörterbuch aus dem Duden-Verlag.

Comment: Letzter Kommentar solte wohl ein Edit sein ;)

Comment: @Jan: Nein, sondern ein Kommentar, der eine Frage aus einem Kommentar von Takkat beantwortet.

Comment: Lass mich das anders ausdrücken: Ich (und sicherlich auch andere) hätten nichts dagegen, wenn du die Quellenangabe in deinen Post integrierst, denn Kommentare sind auf SE nicht für die Ewigkeit gedacht. Drüben auf Chemie werden manchmal sogar schon Posts entfernt, wenn zitiert wird, aber keine Quelle angegeben ist.

Comment: @Jan: German-SE ist keine wissenschaftliche Plattform, daher kann man hier auch nicht die strengen Regeln wissenschaftlicher Publikation anwenden. Darüberhinau wird eine Aussage meines Erachtens nicht dadurch wahrer dass man dazuschreibt, wo man sie gelesen hat. Ich hab auch im Duden schon Behauptungen gelesen, die im Widerspruch zu anderen Quellen standen. Manchmal denke ich auch selber nach und komme auf etwas drauf, das ich dann hier niederschreibe. Ist das dann weniger wert, nur weil ich selbst erarbeitet und nicht irgendwo abgeschrieben habe?

Answer (score 7):

> **Nicht auf die Reihe/Kette kriegen**  bedeutet bildlich, daß wir etwas nicht schaffen, an einer Aufgabe scheitern - wie ein
>   Goldschmied, der nicht imstande ist, die zahllosen Glieder der Kette
>   korrekt zusammenzufügen oder nur eine Anzahl Perlen auf eine Schnur
>   aufzufädeln ([Quelle](http://etymologie.tantalosz.de/n.php))

**Auf die Kette bekommen** oder **Auf die Reihe bekommen** bezieht sich auf die Fähigkeit eine Kette/eine Reihe (von Perlen) [auffädeln](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auffaedeln)/[aufreihen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aufreihen) zu könnten (siehe Bild). Das Auffädeln erfordert dabei Geschicklichkeit. Das **auf** von **auf der Reihe**/**auf der Kette** kann dabei sowohl vom Verb **auffädeln** (Perlen *auf* eine Schnur/ auf eine Reihe auffädeln) oder **aufreihen** (Perlen *auf* eine Schnur aufreihen) kommen.

[image]

Comment: Klingt nicht so plausibel. Die Glieder einer Goldkette sind ja eins wie das andere, so dass die Reihenfolge reichlich wurscht ist, von Anfangs- und Englieder mit dem Kettenschloss abgesehen.

Comment: I'm not a german but I think "Reihe' means a lot of one line dots(line),that's why we can not "in die Reihe bekommen", Reihe is not something like a box.